# Jenkins Update Loses Old Jobs

Tags: jenkins

I am on a redhat linux box. I recently updated Jenkins to version 1.509 only to find that after doing so it has "forgotten" two of my jobs/projects. The jobs can still be found on my Jenkins machine under /var/lib/jenkins/jobs, but they no longer show up in the Jenkins GUI. I attempted to re-create them based off the configuration file I have, but I am not confident I have totally re-created the functionality they had.

I also tried to copy the job and or rename it hoping that would get jenkins to see it, but no luck. I had tried `cp -r /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/JOB1 /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/JOB2`. I also restarted the service a number of times. Finally I updated all of my plugins on the off chance that was somehow related.

So my question is "How can I get Jenkins to notice these jobs?" or failing that "can I run these jobs from in the terminal?"

NOTE: I am not discouraging others from upgrading Jenkins. After I upgraded Jenkins did complain about a number of things which I didn't pay enough attention to which I believe got me into this mess in the first place.

Comment: Did you try triggering a build using the CLI. Like this, java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://<your_jenkins_url> build <your_job_name>

Comment: this could be due to the compatibility of few of the plugins.

Comment: @Vik When I tried your command I get one of the following either "No such command: <my_job_here>" or I get "No such job '<my_job_here>' perhaps you meant '<some_other_job>'" The second one I get when I use the build -c option.

Comment: @OrwellHindenberg - I think amey is right. Probably the missing jobs are using plugin versions that are not compatible with jenkins v1.509

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try the Jenkins CLI (from $JENKINS_URL/cli) and use the create-job command and feed the job configuration file to the cli's stdin.

If that does not help, I would inspect Jenkins log files (you are saving stdout and stderr of Jenkins somewhere, right?) for any errors or clues. If the job failed to load because of some tag that you can guess is provided by a plugin, try to remove that part from the config file.

If that does not help, I would upgrade Jenkins. I think there might be some fixes related to this in the LTS version changelog since 1.509.

And above all... if I were you, I would start making backups of the job configuration files.

I regularly back up the global config.xml, all the job config.xml files and all the plugins. Using these I can set up my Jenkins from scratch. And I do that to set up a test instance where I try any plugin or Jenkins core upgrade. If I see no problems after running a few of the trickiest builds, I know I can upgrade the production instance with much more confidence.